# Efficient way to subtract each element of list from itself in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to subtract each element of a list from itself and produce a list of lists. e.g:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]

# expect this 
x_sub = [[0,1,2,3,4],
         [1,0,1,2,3],
         [2,1,0,1,2],
         [3,2,1,0,1],
         [4,3,2,1,0]]
```

In my case the list has 120,000 members so need something efficient. At the moment this is my code but it is incredibly slow.

```
import time
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(10, size=100000)
allDiffs= []

start = time.time()
# Iterate over each centroid calculating the costs
for i, x in enumerate(data):

    diff = [np.abs(data[i]-a) for a in data]
    allDiffs.append(diff)


end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: If your list has 120,000 elements, then the result from this operation will be an array containing 14.4 billion elements. At 8 bytes per integer (which isn't atypical), that's 115.2 GB. Even with 4 bytes per integer, you need 57.6 GB. How much RAM do you have, and are you sure this is really what you want/need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`numpy.broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
np.abs(data - data[:,None])
```

What happens here is `data[:,None]` reshape data to a 2d array by adding a new axis to it, and `data - data[:,None]` will broadcast twice and generate an outer subtraction of the elements.

---

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.abs(x - x[:,None])

#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#       [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
#       [3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
#       [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Hi Psidom..thanks for that..I find my pc crashes when I try to run your code with a data size of 100000

Comment: It's not so surprising as you end up with 10 billion elements in the result. And with a minimum `np.int8`, you need around 10GB memory to store it.

Comment: Thanks, that's why I opted for an on the fly method as I was doing. Do you know any way to speed up my code? thanks

Comment: So with your method, your pc runs fine?

Comment: Yes but would take 7 hours to execute

Comment: Thanks will look at that